# Why does my screen show noise when coming back from sleep using Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome, suspend

I am using:

- Ubuntu 19.10 (but the same thing happens on 18-19) (on Xorg)
- Gnome shell
- The Nvidia proprietary display driver

When my computer goes to sleep and then turns back on screen content, regardless of the color, turns to noise.

i.e. Web browser

**Before sleep**

[image: before sleep image]

**After sleep**

[image: after sleep image]

I can't get the noise to get off my background until I reboot.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Both my desktop and login screen do this in 19.04. It’s quite bad and never goes away until reboot.

Comment: I am now on 19.10 and have the same issue on my desktop background (which is black) - no solution yet.